# problema al compilar source

Tags: visual-studio

me encuentro compilando un source publico de un programa, el cual al momento de intentar compilar el mismo, no para de arrojarme errores. no soy un experto del tema, pero quería ver si alguien me puede guiar, quizás me este faltando algo para poder compilar el mismo?

edit: agrego el codigo para poder verlo mejor segun la imagen que adjunto, pude resolver varios errores, pero me queda en este punto pidiendo una definicion.

```
    public event KeyboardHookCallback
    {
        add
        {
            KeyboardHookCallback keyDown = this.KeyDown;
            while (true)
            {
                KeyboardHookCallback a = keyDown;
                KeyboardHookCallback callback3 = (KeyboardHookCallback) Delegate.Combine(a, value);
                keyDown = Interlocked.CompareExchange<KeyboardHookCallback>(ref this.KeyDown, callback3, a);
                if (ReferenceEquals(keyDown, a))
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            KeyboardHookCallback keyDown = this.KeyDown;
            while (true)
            {
                KeyboardHookCallback source = keyDown;
                KeyboardHookCallback callback3 = (KeyboardHookCallback) Delegate.Remove(source, value);
                keyDown = Interlocked.CompareExchange<KeyboardHookCallback>(ref this.KeyDown, callback3, source);
                if (ReferenceEquals(keyDown, source))
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que lenguaje? que errores?

Comment: y que versión de visual? normalmente ese tipo de proyectos te indican con la versión de visual que fueron compilados.

Comment: desconesco que vercion, yo utilizo la 2019, pero donde puedo ver con que fue escrito?

Comment: respecto al lenguaje, entiendo que es C++ ?

Comment: lo debería decir en el repositorio donde obtuviste el proyecto.

Comment: lo baje de un foro, es una aplicación que publicaron el sorce. pero no dieron detalles del mismo.

Comment: este es el mismo: 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aoWNwDoXEU8PpUW3WmFECT8grgSBjE-O/view?usp=sharing